# trouble in implementing the new xml link for the yahoo rss feed

Tags: yql, yahoo-weather-api

I am having trouble in implementing the new xml link for the yahoo rss feed. Following is the code that i need to implement the new xml url. Can anyone please tell me how i can do it, thanks!

```
String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in(select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\") and u='" + unit + "'", location);

String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));
URL url = new URL(endpoint);
```

Problem is I'm not getting the api data. On running the application it crashes and shows FATAL EXCEPTION error on YQL endpoint.

I don't know exactly what to put for query in this endpoint url -- query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json I don't know what should pass after yql?q=____________

Comment: And what is the problem? Please specify what doesn't work.

Comment: @james Elderfield  i dont know exactly what too put for querry  in this endpoint url -- https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json      I don't know what should pass after yql?q=____________